# How to create responsive screen for every device in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a screen as attached. Stack position is not responsive for low resolution device. So how can I create this screen to fix in any device?

home_Screen.dart

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/ui/home/components/menu.dart';
import '../../helper/constants.dart';
import '../../helper/enum.dart';
import '../chanting/chanting_catalog_screen.dart';
import '../monk/monk_screen.dart';
import '../radio/radio_screen.dart';
import '../youtube/video_screen.dart';
import 'components/monk_carousel.dart';
import 'components/myanmar_calender.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/home';
  final BuildContext? menuScreenContext;
  final Function? onScreenHideButtonPressed;
  final bool hideStatus;
  const HomeScreen(
      {Key? key,
      this.menuScreenContext,
      this.onScreenHideButtonPressed,
      this.hideStatus = false})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final _itemsView = GlobalKey();
  double _stackHeight = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      RenderBox stackRB =
          _itemsView.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      setState(() {
        _stackHeight = stackRB.size.height;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              height: screenHeight * 0.7,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 30, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                      Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                    ],
                    stops: const [
                      0.0,
                      0.5,
                      0.7,
                    ],
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            width: screenWidth * 0.70,
                            //height: screenHeight * 0.20,
                            //color: Colors.black,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 10, left: 10, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  kHomeTitle1,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  kHomeTitle2,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  kHomeTitle3,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: screenWidth * 0.30,
                          height: screenHeight * 0.15,
                          
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/images/buddha.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.contain),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: screenHeight * 0.15,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 10),
                      child: const MyanmarCalender(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: screenHeight * 0.30,
              key: _itemsView,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(70),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        MenuButton(
                          screenWidth: screenWidth,
                          iconData: Icons.music_video,
                          screen: const MonkScreen(
                            title: kMenuMp3,
                            screenMode: MonkScreenMode.song,
                            albumType: AlbumType.dhamatalk,
                          ),
                          title: kMenuMp3,
                        ),
                        MenuButton(
                          screenWidth: screenWidth,
                          iconData: Icons.play_lesson_rounded,
                          screen: const MonkScreen(
                            title: kMenuLecture,
                            screenMode: MonkScreenMode.lecture,
                            albumType: AlbumType.lecture,
                          ),
                          title: kMenuLecture,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        MenuButtonWithImageIcon(
                          screenWidth: screenWidth,
                          assetImage:
                              const AssetImage('assets/images/book.jpeg'),
                          screen: const MonkScreen(
                            title: kMenuEbook,
                            screenMode: MonkScreenMode.book,
                            albumType: AlbumType.ebook,
                          ),
                          title: kMenuEbook,
                        ),
                        MenuButtonWithImageIcon(
                          screenWidth: screenWidth,
                          assetImage:
                              const AssetImage('assets/images/prayer.png'),
                          screen: const ChantingCatalogScreen(),
                          title: kMenuChantig,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        MenuButton(
                          screenWidth: screenWidth,
                          iconData: Icons.video_camera_front_outlined,
                          screen: const VideoScreen(),
                          title: kLiveStreaming,
                          withNavBar: false,
                        ),
                        MenuButton(
                          screenWidth: screenWidth,
                          iconData: Icons.radio,
                          screen: const RadioScreen(),
                          title: kOnlineRadio,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    const AutoSizeText(
                      kLatestDhama,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    const MonkCarousel(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: _stackHeight + (screenHeight * 0.45),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

iPhone 13 pro max vs iPhone 8

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **mediaQuery** class which is a built-in component in Flutter to get the user's specifications - height and width etc - and then define some terms to suit their design size 
for example:

```
Container(
    width: mediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, 
    height: 150, 
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/buddha.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.contain),
```

In this example we told the container width to take 50% of the screen width on any devise, you can use it wherever you want. 
 you can read more about it in the official docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html

Comment: Actually, I used MediaQuery but it is not working either. Anyway, I add the width and height with mediaQuery for buddha image. I also update the code and iPhone 8 vs iPhone 13 comparing image for clear understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can create static class for size

```
class AppSize{
 static double width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
 static double height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
 }
```

if you want use like that

```
Container(
    width: AppSize.width * 0.1 , 
    height: AppSize.height * 0.6 , 
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/buddha.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.contain),
```

Comment: Actually, I used MediaQuery but it is not working either. Anyway, I add the width and height with mediaQuery for buddha image. I also update the code and iPhone 8 vs iPhone 13 comparing image for clear understanding